# How To Detect Pushbutton pressing?

Tags: winapi

Im trying to build simple application (Using Win32 API) which shows a black window within a button which should close the application, The problem is that I cant figure out how detect a PushBotton click.

Little peace of my code for example:

```
HWND hButton = CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"),TEXT("Exit"),WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,100,100,50,50,hWnd,0,hInstance,0);
```

Comment: If you didnt notice, the main subject here is Win32

Comment: There are tons of Win32 programming tutorials. Most explain how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Briefly, you need to give the button an ID and then handle `WM_COMMAND` messages from that button in your window proc.  The article at http://www.infernodevelopment.com/c-win32-api-tutorial gives a decent example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to analyze WM_COMMAND
 message in main window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(  
HWND hwnd,        // handle to window  
UINT uMsg,        // message identifier  
WPARAM wParam,    // first message parameter  
LPARAM lParam)    // second message parameter  
{   
if ((uMsg == WM_COMMAND) && ((HWND)lParam == hButton))  //check MSDN for WM_COMMAND and BN_CLICKED notifications
{  
    //button was pressed  
}  
.......  
}
```